# Partitioning the set of divisors into two sets with equal product

Tags: nt.number-theory

Inspired with this [PROBLEM](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/474899/divisors-of-qkpr) I am interested in those natural numbers that the set of their divisors can be partitioned into two sets with equal product. For example we can decompose divisors of $8$ into $\lbrace 1,8\rbrace$ and $\lbrace 2,4\rbrace$. Is the sequence of this numbers well-known? Is there any characterization for them ? Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: each prime has to be raised to an odd power

Comment: not so: for 16, we have {1,2,16} and {4,8}.

Comment: The product of all the divisors of $n$ equals $n^{\tau(n)/2}$, where $\tau(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$. (This can be easily proved with a pairing argument.) If the divisors of $n$ can be partitioned in the desired way, it follows that the product of all divisors of $n$ is a perfect square. Therefore a necessary condition is that $n^{\tau(n)}$ be a perfect 4th power; in other words, either $\tau(n)$ is a multiple of 4, or $n$ is a 4th power. I suspect that this necessary condition is also sufficient.

Comment: So I guess that what I should have said is each prime should be raised to a power that is congruent to 2 or 3 modulo 4.

Comment: Numbers whose divisors multiply to a square are tabulated at http://oeis.org/A048943 --- it says, $n$ is a 4th power, or $n$ has at least two prime factors with odd multiplicities, or $n$ has at least one prime factor with multiplicity 3 modulo 4.

Comment: I think this is a great puzzle, but it does not appear to be about research mathematics, and would be better suited for M.SE.

Answer (score 5):

Gerry Myerson comments that $n$ can only satisfy this condition if it is a 4th power, or has at least two prime factors with odd multiplicities, or has at least one prime factor with multiplicity 3 modulo 4. This is also sufficient.

Case 1: If $n$ has two prime factors with odd multiplicities, say $p^a$ and $q^b$, then one of the sets in your partition is the set of divisors which have (a power of $p$ which ranges from 0 through $\frac{a-1}{2}$) XOR (a power of $q$ which ranges from 0 through $\frac{b-1}{2}$).

Case 2: If $n$ has at least one prime factor with multiplicity 3 modulo 4, say $p^a$, then one of the sets in your partition is the set of divisors which have a power of $p$ which is 0 or 3 (mod 4). Note that in this case, both of the sets in your partition contain the same number of divisors.

Case 3: If $n$ is a perfect fourth power, let its prime factors be $p_1<p_2<...<p_k$. Then call one of the sets in your partition $S$. A divisor is in $S$ if and only if it is $1$, or its lowest prime factor has multiplicity 0 or 1 (mod 4).

You can check that all of these constructions work out. It's easiest to think about this problem by trying to find a "balanced" partition of the lattice of $n$'s divisors.